# Unable to 'include' php files on Xampp on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I have Xampp running on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a php page in which i've included another file like `include 'dbconfig.php'`. But whenever I try to open the page I get an error like this:

```
Warning: require(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 2
```

I have tried using the relative path, the full path and everything. I have also double-checked that `dbconfig.php` IS present in the same folder as `index.php`. I googled around a bit and i think the problem is that php is unable to open `dbconfig.php`because of 'permission' issues.

I'm new to ubuntu, so I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone please help me out?

The code from `index.php` goes like this :

```
<?php
    include 'dbconfig.php';
?>
```

Comment: put the code from `/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php` on **line 2**

Comment: (1)  Find out what user your webserver runs as.  (2)  Check the permissions on your file (`ls -al dbconfig.php`).  (3)  Make sure the webserver has permission to read dbconfig.php.

Comment: @CullyLarson, I got this as the permissions: -rwxrwxrwx 1 harsha harsha 0 May 27 11:39 /opt/lampp/htdocs/dbconfig.php

Comment: @MohammadFaisal, i was just testing whether include was working or not. The code from index.php is like this <?php include 'dbconfig.php'; ?>

Comment: Edit your question and include the pertinent part of your code from index.php

Comment: If you don't care about local safty chmod the whole htdocs folder including everything inside and set it to something like chmod 775 or even 777. If that doesn't help - then it's definatly not a permission/rights problem. - Dont't do that if you arn't totaly MAD at it :)

Comment: You could try putting this in your `index.php` before your include:  `if( !is_file('dbconfig.php') ) echo "Not a file."; if( !is_readable('dbconfig.php') ) echo "Not readable";`

Comment: @ThatMSG, can u tell me how to set it through chmod? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: @CullyLarson, i added that line but it's not echoing anything.

Comment: Try this:  `echo "<pre>" . file_get_contents('dbconfig.php') . "</pre>";`  Does it output the file's contents?

Comment: @CullyLarson, it's returning this error : Warning: file_get_contents(dbconfig.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 4

Comment: Try creating another file (with something like "hello there" in it), in that directory, and do the `file_get_contents` thing on it.

Comment: Also, run this on the command-line and paste the output here:  `ls -al \`readlink -f dbconfig.php\``

Comment: @CullyLarson, I'm sorry, there was a typo when i first used the file_get_contents which is why I was getting that error. I fixed it now and that error has disappeared although it's not showing the contents of that file. I have made a new .txt file and tried file_get_contents on it and it's showing the contents of that .txt file though

Comment: Try running this from the command line:  `cat dbconfig.php > dbconfig2.php` and then change your include line to: `include("dbconfig2.php");`

Comment: @pale_rider Then your `dbconfig.php` file is not in the same directory as your `index.php` file

Comment: If you run `ls` do you see `index.php` and `dbconfig.php` in the same directory?  If you do, run `pwd`.  Is the output `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`?  I'm thinking you may be editing another version of `index.php` somewhere else or something.

Comment: I can see the files in the same directory when i run ls. Then i ran pwd and it's showing home/harsha and not /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Comment: @pale_rider There you have it

Comment: @CullyLarson, does this mean it's been looking for dbconfig.php in home/harsha ? Can u please tell how to fix it?

Comment: No, it's been looking for it in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` which is where your webserver is serving files from.  You're editing files in your home directory, which your webserver has no idea about.  If you actually go to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`, you'll see your original `index.php` file which you probably created a while ago, and no `dbconfig.php` file.  You could just copy the `dbconfig.php` file you've been working on in your home directory to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` if you'd like.

Comment: @CullyLarson, Thanks. I went to the home directory and found a dbconfig.php there although i don't remember creating one there. I copied it to htdocs and replaced it with that was already there. Still the same warnings.

Comment: Then go back and do all the things I suggested, but actually in the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` directory.  You're basically trying to narrow down your problem.  Is it a permission issue?  How can you find out?  Does the file actually exist?  How can you find out?  Is it a problem with the file itself?  Would it happen with another file? Etc.

Comment: @CullyLarson, ok tnx. I will. It's actually able to find the file and read it. I know that through 'is_file' and 'is_readable'.